# How do I config Visual Studio Code to open .mak file as Makefile

Tags: visual-studio-code

Normally Visual Studio Code open file namely "Makefile" correctly (marking color). But other makefile with arbitrary name like "makefile.mak",... It can not mark color for the file.

How can I associate some file to open as makefile in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 1):

- Open the settings
- Add file associations for the arbitrary file extensions:

  ```
  "files.associations": {
    "*.mak": "makefile",
    "*.make": "makefile"
  }
  ```